# How To Delete/Filter all the rows that contain text from another column

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formatting, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Hello,

What Im trying to do is filter the First Name and Last Name columns by looking up all the values in E column and remove/filter.

So for example, first name in E column is Robert, what I would like is to be able to remove everybody named Robert from column A and B (I would like to remove the entire row, meaning both A and B column if the name is matching E column). And also for every other name in the E column

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:B; NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E; A2:A)))
```

[image]